# Round a number and keep trailing zeroes in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g, rounding

Okay, so (say) I have a number like **7836.721**. I want an oracle query that can give me the following result :

```
7837.000
```

The number should be rounded up to one's place and all the digits after the decimal get converted to zeros.

What I have used :

```
select round(7836.721,0) from dual
```

which gave me :

```
7837
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need to_char...

```
SELECT to_char(TRUNC(7836.721), '9999990.000') numbr
FROM   dual;

NUMBR
------------
    7837.000
```

This does assume that you're after 3 decimal places for any number, rather than 7.12 going to 7.00.

---

ETA:

It seems like a very strange requirement, but here you go:

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT 123 numbr FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 123.12 numbr FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 123.1234 numbr FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 123.12345 numbr FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 0.12345 numbr FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 1.2345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123e50 numbr FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT NULL numbr FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 1.23e-50 numbr FROM dual)
SELECT numbr,
       ROUND(numbr) || CASE WHEN numbr != TRUNC(numbr) THEN 
                                 RPAD('.', LENGTH(numbr -TRUNC(numbr)), '0') END new_numbr
FROM   sample_data;

     NUMBR NEW_NUMBR
---------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       123 123
    123.12 123.00
  123.1234 123.0000
 123.12345 123.00000
   0.12345 0.00000
1.23456789 1.2345678901234567890123456789012346E+50

  1.23E-50 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Yes, your query did the trick but what if i the places after the decimals are not fixed to 3.

Comment: I would be curious as to why you wanted to output the trailing 0s after the decimal point, in that case. A number is the same regardless of how many trailing 0s there are after the decimal point. Plus, you'd usually expect the output to be consistent, if you're using a given format - i.e. all numbers shown to the same number of decimal places.

Comment: I get your curiosity. The trailing zeros were needed for presentation purpose in a table. Now, if i have different number of digits after decimal in a column then how can i achieve the needful in a dynamic way?
Is there a possibility?

Comment: What is the presentation purpose? Just so you know how many decimal places there were before the truncation? If so, why do you need to know that?

Comment: I need the format for my work purpose. That should be enough for a reason i guess. I just want to know if this is possible with varying number of digits after decimal.

Comment: I'm curious because it seems like a very strange requirement, and I can't think of a reason why. Anyway, I've updated my answer with something that will hopefully do the trick...

Comment: Thanks. I agree that the requirement is quite strange but it is what it is.
Thank you for all the help, though.

Comment: A slight edit as I forgot to remove the -1 from the rpad.

Comment: Edit again then since the number i gave you was 783**6**.721. Then you would use round to convert it to simple **7837** and then apply the other function to conclude. I am kidding though.

Comment: Hah! Yes, I missed that! *{;-) Note that it's just the initial TRUNC that needed to be changed; the logic remains the same to generate the trailing 0s

Comment: Yes! That is why i did not mentioned it earlier as the logic seemed quite clear and was helpful enough to solve my problem.